# Textarea text overlaps the popup content in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, textarea

I struggle with IE trying to fix the following issue. IE renders textarea text over popup div with my configuration, the input text has no such effect. Chrome renders well the both.

```css
html, body, body > div {
  height: 100%;
}

input, textarea {
 width: 300px;
  color: tomato;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="dropdown">
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div>option</div>
    <div>option</div>
    <div>option</div>
    <div>option</div>
    <div>option</div>
    <div>option</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <input value="very long long long long long long  long long long long long long text">
  </div>
 <div class="item">
    <textarea rows="4">very long long long long long long  long long long long long long text</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

- [IE 11 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30WLW.png)
- [Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL48J.png)

Does anybody face the same issue? How could I fix it?

Comment: Did you get this working in IE? Even i am facing same issue

Comment: Yes, I had changed the initial composition and it works well.